# strange object instance behaviour in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a class using Python unittest, but the test suite seems to be modifying the base class

here's some pseudo code to demonstrate the problem:

the class

```
// module cards...
class deck():

    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.__cards = cards

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__cards)

    def draw(self, n = 1):
        '''
        remove and return n cards
        from internal card list

        n -- integer
        @return list removed
        '''
        removed      = self.__cards[0:n]
        remaining    = self.__cards[n:]
        self.__cards = remaining
        return removed

    def addOne(self, card):
        '''
        add single card to the deck
        '''
        self.__cards.append(card)

    def addMany(self, cards):
        '''
        add many cards to the deck
        '''
        self.__cards.extend(cards)
```

a fixture to populate the instance, will probably be the output of a file or DB query

```
//source
src = [
{
    'id'          : 1,
    'name'        : 'one',
    'description' : 'this is one'
},
{
    'id'          : 2,
    'name'        : 'two',
    'description' : 'this is two'
},
{
    'id'          : 3,
    'name'        : 'three',
    'description' : 'this is three'
},
{
    'id'          : 4,
    'name'        : 'four',
    'description' : 'this is four'
},
{
    'id'          : 5,
    'name'        : 'five',
    'description' : 'this is five'
}
]
```

the tests

```
from source import src
import cards 

def test_drawRemovesOne(self):
    deck = cards.deck(src)
    self.assertTrue(callable(deck.draw))

    # single card
    deckSize  = len(deck)
    drawnCard = deck.draw(1)
    self.assertEqual(drawnCard[0]['id'], 1)
    self.assertEqual(4, len(deck))
    self.assertEqual(len(drawnCard), 1)



def test_drawRemovesMany(self):
    deck = cards.deck(src)
    deckSize   = len(deck)
    drawnCards = deck.draw(3)
    self.assertEqual(drawnCards[0]['id'], 1)
    self.assertEqual(drawnCards[1]['id'], 2)
    self.assertEqual(drawnCards[2]['id'], 3)
    self.assertEqual(len(deck), 2)
    self.assertEqual(len(drawnCards), 3)


'''
INVALIDATES PREVIOUS TESTS...
def test_addOne(self):
    deck = cards.deck(src)
    card = {
        'id'          : 9,
        'name'        : 'nine',
        'description' : 'this is nine'
    }
    deckSize = len(deck)
    deck.addOne(card)
    newDeckSize = len(deck)
    self.assertTrue(newDeckSize == deckSize + 1)
'''
```

EDIT: posted real snippet

the first test passes, but then subsequently fails when second test is implemented. It seems as if there is one reference to the class being shared by the test methods, despite appearing to be fresh instances.

I've only done a nominal bit of work in Python, is this the result of some language peculiarity I'm unaware of?

Comment: self.collection.pop() in removeOne method?

Comment: Take a step back. You sure your `removeOne` does what it should? The code you posted here doesn't. There is no way the list or `MyClass` object is shared *with the code you posted here*. Maybe you made an error while simplifying it?

Comment: sorry, updated snippet. The wierd thing is that the first test passes, but the later test invalidates it - it seems to modify the same class instance.

Comment: Post some code which actually demonstrates the problem, not pseudo code

Comment: Are you sure you haven't oversimplified the test case? Is the object instantiation happening exactly as posted, or are you relying on some `setUp()`?

Comment: @Yuval - no, I had originally used setUp, but have tried using fresh instances in each case to get to the bottom of it. AH! maybe it's because I'm passing in a list of dicts to the __init__, maybe the methods are modifying the reference to that list?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're doing here. What is `cards.deck()`? What's `src`?

Comment: src is a list of dicts, cards.deck is the class inside the cards module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code

```
>>> class Deck:
...     def __init__(self, cards):
...         self.cards = cards
>>> l0 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d1 = Deck(l0)
>>> d2 = Deck(l0)
>>> d1.cards
0: [1, 2, 3]
>>> d2.cards
1: [1, 2, 3]
>>> d1.cards.append(4)
>>> d2.cards
2: [1, 2, 3, 4]    # d1 and d2 share the same list for cards
```

You start both your tests with `deck = cards.deck(src)` but I don't know where that `src` is coming from. If it isn't created in your setUp method as a new object then it could be being shared between the test cases.

Comment: I'm thinking that's the issue too - I'm trying to use a list contained in a separate file as a fixture so I'm guessing the reference in the class is global, and being modified each time.